# Sqlalchemy-Python Plus two Base Query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to have a collection containing these two base query. How can I do that?

I have tried using operator '+' like List but it doesn't work.

My code's here:

```
question1 = Question.query.filter_by(question_hard=1).order_by(func.random()).limit(10)
question2 = Question.query.filter_by(question_hard=2).order_by(func.random()).limit(20)
```

Looking for something like this:
`question = question1 + question2`

Answer (score 3):

You can use it this way:

```
question = question1.union(question2)
```

[sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried putting ```all()``` after ```limit()``` and then I plus them like List. Fortunately, it also worked!